# Linearly Independent Vectors - maximum size subset

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Among the vectors $(1; 0; 1), (2; 1; 3), (3; 1; 2), (3; 1; 0)$ find a maximum size subset of linearly independent vectors and provide an argument that they indeed are linearly independent. Is this subset unique?

I understand how to prove if vectors are linearly independent but I really cannot understand how to structure the whole thing. The form that the vectors are given in I cannot understand how to arrange them if that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You shouldn't have used the `linear-programming` tag.

Comment: do you need to prove that the maximum size of linearly independent vectors over $\Bbb R^n$ is $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

These are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence the maximum size can only be at most $3$, if you can find three vectors which are linearly independent then you are done.

To show that $3$ vectors are indeed linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can find $3$ vectors and form a matrix using them and compute the determinant, if the determinant is non-zero, then they are linearly independent.

Try to find two such sets to show that it is indeed not unique.

Comment: Okay since the size of the vectors is 3x1 I can only choose 3 vectors from the given vectors. Since neither of the vectors are a multiple of any other given vector choosing any 3 vectors from the given ones makes them independent. Am I right? Also can you explain further how to prove whether the subset is unique? Many Thanks!

Comment: pick $3$ of them and check if they are independent. you can check by using the determinant or use the definition of linearly independent, i.e. solve a linear system. Basis is not unique, find another set of $3$ vectors and prove that it is also linearly independent.

Comment: Yeah I understand now! Thank you so much! :)